# How to make the thumbnail pager dynamically in bxslider?

Tags: php, bxslider

I'm using bxslider to show images from the database, it works but the thumbnails of the caroussels isn't clickable.

This is the code what I use;

```
<?php if ($object->fotos->has()): ?>
            <ul class="bxslider">
            <?php foreach ($object->fotos as $foto): ?>
                <?php $photo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($foto->ID, 'large'); ?>
                <li><img src="<?= $photo[0] ?>"></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>

            <div id="bx-pager">
            <?php foreach ($object->fotos as $foto): ?>
                <?php $photo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($foto->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
          <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="<?= $photo[0] ?>" /></a>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

I tried:

```
<div id="bx-pager">
            <?php foreach ($object->fotos as $foto): ?>
                <?php $photo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($foto->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
          <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="<?= $photo[0] ?>" /></a>
          <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="<?= $photo[1] ?>" /></a>
          <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="<?= $photo[2] ?>" /></a>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
```

This is clickable but it doesn't show the image. How can I make the thumbnail images clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Check This 
  `http://jsfiddle.net/L5S2B/2/` 
I think it should be work, If its not than feel to get back

Below is the HTML and grab Javascript from Fiddle

```
<!-- slider 1 -->
<ul class="bxslider">
</ul>

<!-- custom controls -->
<div class="bxslider-controls">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">PREV</a>
  <a class="pull-right" href="#">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this will work if I change it a little bit but I use another slider; jcarousel-master 

it works now